# Windows 7 или Windows 8 для С++Builder 6

Tags: c++builder, windows

Здравствуйте.

В С++ билдере 6 при запуске приложения, а потом при его коррекции, выбивает ошибку и приходиться либо создавать новое приложение и копировать текст программы туда, и так пока приложение не будет полностью законченное, то есть приходиться начинать новое приложение столько раз в зависимости от сложности проекта.

Что делал.

1. лазил в директорию, указывал пути к библиотекам и так далее;
2. лазил в компилятор, там выставил в 1 ряде справа в NONE (не помню, как называется);
3. переустанавливал билдер кучу раз и без разницы эффект тот же

   ```
   [ILINK32 Error] Fatal: Could not open Debug\Project1.exe (program still running?)
   ```

Сейчас на Embarcadero RAD Studio 2010 там та же ошибка. Поэтому спрашиваю, что делать лечится ли это на Windows 7 и есть ли такие ошибки, если работать на Windows 8. Google не помог.

Comment: Похоже на баг. Вопрос висит без ответа на Embarcadero Forums: https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=116421

Answer (score 1):

1. Скачать переносимую (portable) версию билдера и опробовать, если то же самое, то проблема на компе.
2. Проверить, есть ли дебаг версия и правильно ли указан путь.
3. Если есть в адресе установки билдера или проекта русские буквы, то убрать их.

Comment: Да с этим решено но как быть если я запускаю консольное приложение оно показываеться и тутже закрываеться что не возможно успеть прочитать что там написано и функция getch() - не помогаэт то есть мне нужно чтобы програма ожыдала нажатия клавишы и только тогда закрывалась. Раньше такого не было.

Comment: в билдере консольные не делал но в вижуале system("pause");

это разумеется если консоль закрывается после выполнения работы а не рушится

заодно ответь что именно было и как исправил (дабы если кто другой найдёт твой вопрос  то смогли сделать тоже самое)

Comment: system("pause") - увы, говнокод

Менее плохо - getch() или while(!kbhit())

А еще лучше - согрешите... (сделайте ввод cin)

Comment: system("pause") - увы, говнокод --- почему???

Comment: Ввод сделал не помогло!

Comment: у тебя: консоль запускается -> работает -> в конце работы закрывается без паузы.

или:  консоль запускается -> тут же вырубается.

Comment: Увы, проблема не в этом. Вопрос висит открытым на Embarcadero Forums: https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=116421